# Documents do not appear in Azure Documents

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In a Test application i want to create search indexes.

I have a list of objects which I want to send to the azure search index.

With the following code I create the index itself:

```
  await client.Indexes.CreateAsync(myIndexDefinition);
```

This works and I can see the index in the portal with the defined fields.

Now I try to add a document.

```
using (SearchIndexClient index = client.Indexes.GetClient(cityIndexName))
{
     List<IndexAction> items = cities.Select(CreatecCtion).ToList();

     var batch = new IndexBatch(items);
     await index.Documents.IndexAsync(batch);
}
```

[...]

```
private IndexAction CreateACtion(city city)
{  
    var doc = new Document
    {
        { "CityId", city.Id }
    };

    var action = new IndexAction(IndexActionType.Upload, doc);

    return action;
}
```

After running the code the result of all items says that they were successfull and conain the Id I set. But when I look in the portal of this index the count is 0.

Any hint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index stats are updated asynchronously. Even if you call `Indexes.GetStats`, the results will be a little bit behind. If you want an accurate doc count right after indexing, use `Documents.Count`.

Answer (score 1):

Murphy's law. Now (after someting about 30 Minutes of last update) they are appearing.

It looks like the statistics on the mainpage are not refreshed immediatly.

Hope this helps someone else :)